# c# WFA Buttons reorder

Tags: c#, button, visual-studio-2013

so i am working on a project with WFA C# in Visual Studio,
and i have a project with 20 buttons a page, now the problem is:
i have placed buttons but they are not ordered correctly:

[image]

now im wondering if there is a function in Visual studio to automaticly switch the buttons around so it is like:

button1 button2 button3 button4

button5 button6 button7 button8

etc?

can anybody help me with this?

or do i have to manually reorder them?

Comment: Which container (`Panel`, `TableLayoutPanel`, ...) are you using? If you're starting a new project `WPF` is the better choise, to solve this so you can use `WrapPanel`, `Grid`, `UniformGrid`...

Comment: sory forgot to tell, they are all inside a panel

Comment: Are you creating the buttons dynamically?

Comment: no i created them using drag and drop